# Distinct counts using Apache Spark DataFrame or SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My Schema looks like below:

```
scala> airing.printSchema()
root
 |-- program: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- detail: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- contributors: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- contributorId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- order: long (nullable = true)
```

I need to count based on the unique Actors, to find the most popular actors.
My code is as:

```
val castCounts = airing.groupBy("program.detail.contributors.name").count().sort(desc("count")).take(10)
```

To my shock, I am getting duplicates as shown in the below snapshot. I expected each individual actor to occur once, with a distinct count:
[image]

Printing the results below:

```
[WrappedArray(),4344]
[WrappedArray(Matt Smith),16]
[WrappedArray(Phil Keoghan),15]
[WrappedArray(Don Adams, Barbara Feldon, Edward Platt),10]
[WrappedArray(Edward Platt, Don Adams, Barbara Feldon),10]
```

Comment: You can use dropDuplicates() function to avoid duplicates. Thanks.

Comment: can you add the output of res.mkString("\n") if res is your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 steps 
use `explode` function to make your data flat so each row of data only have 1 contributor.

```
  val df = airing.withColumn("contributor", explode(col("program.detail.contributors"))))
```

Get result from new df which contributor has been exploded.

```
  val castCounts = df.groupBy("contributor.name").count().sort(desc("count")).take(10)
```

Comment: Above approach worked perfectly, till I encountered some Japanese data. Now facing a new exception: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: optional binary element (UTF8) is not a group @giaosudau any idea?

Comment: @user2849678 I think this error is about the schema of the data more than the Spark SQL.
https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/2329